# ActiveStorage image_tag wrong hostname when deployed with docker and nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, nginx, rails-activestorage

Im using ActiveStorage in Rails 6. Everything worked fine until I migrate my app from heroku to an AWS EC2 server.

My stack is composed by:

A docker container with the `puma` applications server named `application_server`

A docker container with nginx named `nginx`

The problem is that when I use the `image_tag` helper passing as param a model entity in my view, it is resolved as follow

```
<img alt="..." src="http://application_server/rails/active_storage/representations/redirect/....jpg?locale=it">
```

and not

```
<img alt="..." src="https://my-domain.com/rails/active_storage/representations/redirect/...jpg?locale=it">
```

As I would expect.

The two containers share the same docker network and the `nginx` configuration is the following one:

```
upstream application_server {
    server application_server:3000;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my-domain.com;
    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }    
    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name my-domai.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-domain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-domain.com/privkey.pem;
    
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://application_server/;
    }
}
```

I can't understand if it there is something wrong with nginx or with activestorage

Answer (score 0):

```
server
{
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name my-domain.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-domain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-domain.com/privkey.pem;
    
    location /
    {
        proxy_pass http://application_server;
        proxy_redirect 'http://application_server/' 'https://my-domain.com/';
        sub_filter_once off;
        sub_filter_types "*";
        sub_filter 'http://application_server' 'https://my-domain.com';
    }
}
```

Completly untested.

- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect
- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html

If you have nginx-extras or openresty you could also try sub**s**_filter (note the additional `s`) for additional regex support.

Keep in mind that sub(s)_filter will not directly work, when you have dynamically generated links via JavaScript. You than have to modifiy the JavaScript (via sub(s)_filter).

If `proxy_redirect` is not working you could try Lua. Check your redirects via `curl -IL <URL>`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This could be a patch, but as you mention some url are generated via javascript. I'd like to understand why Rails Active Storage helper are generating links with container name as host to configure it correctly.